# Using the Affine Maxima Package

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, computer-algebra

The Maxima computer algebra system has a package called Affine for doing the calculations implicit in Bergman's [diamond lemma](http://stanford.edu/~khare/diamond.pdf) for rings.  It can be viewed as a kind of noncommutative analogue of Buchberger's algorithm to compute Groebner bases, though it's not guaranteed to terminate.

Affine was written by William Schelter, and was written by him to do the calculations in the paper *Graded Algebras of Global dimension 3*, Adv. Math. 66 (1987), by Schelter and Michael Artin.  This is the paper that introduced what are now known as Artin-Schelter regular algebras, which is an area of active research in noncomnmutative ring theory.  (Lieven LeBruyn has some reminiscences of Schelter, his work, and the role of Affine in that work at [his blog](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/bill-schelters-maxima.html).)

I was interested in using Affine to do similar calculations, but the existing [documentation](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_24.html) is quite poor.  Does anyone know how to use it, or can point me to better documentation?  I'm just interested in the most basic application: taking a set of generators and relations for a noncommutative algebra for a field, an ordering on variables, and using Affine to compute what relations I have to add to resolve overlap ambiguities.

In particular, I would like to use it to check the calculations in the paper [Artin-Schelter regular algebras of dimension five](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5129).

Comment: This is a computer algebra system question, not a mathematics question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of a CAS. While CAS use is not explicitly mentioned in the MO faq, questions on CAS use is [on topic at MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and you should consider asking there instead.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed.  I'm asking about an algorithm that's used in research-level mathematics.  The only people who would have ever heard of it are mathematical researchers, and the only reason you would ever want to apply it is in the context of research into noncommutative algebras.

Comment: I apologize for providing insufficient context.  I've added some more detail.

Comment: @arsmath : I am not an expert in the rules for MathOverflow, but I think that if there is any doubt, you should try MathStackExchange first.  This may be a "research level question", but a lot of very smart and knowledgeable people post at MSE and I am pretty sure you would get a good answer there.  If you don't, then come back here.  If you post at both sites simultaneously, you should state so in both places, with links to the other sites.

Comment: I don't get why this is controversial.  Schelter wrote the package as part of research-level mathematics, and I would like to use it to check calculations in other research-level mathematics.

Comment: I cast a vote to reopen. This looks like a question that would be of interest to research mathematicians, and that should be the benchmark. (Similarly, one can find many teaching questions, and even a dustless chalk question, which are evidently not research math questions but are evidently of great interest to research mahematicians.)

Comment: I had previously cast a vote to re-open (the first time round) for much the same reasons as @ToddTrimble